# UIScrollView won't scroll on iOS 7 after popping the view controller

Tags: uiwebview, uiscrollview, ios7

My app's home screen has a UIScrollView that contains a UIWebView and a UIButton. The scroll view's content size is set accordingly after loading the web view.

The user can return to the home screen at anytime by simply pressing an icon in a tab bar. This action clears all of the view controllers out of the navigation controller and adds the home screen's controller to the navigation controller. The home screen is redisplayed correctly and the scroll view works just fine.

The problem I'm encountering is when the user presses a "back" button to return the to home screen, which pops the current view controller. The page redisplays fine, but you can't scroll anymore.

I've stepped through the code numerous times and the scroll view's content size is being set to the same value no matter which way you return to the home screen.

It's important to note that the scrollview only stops working under iOS 7. It works as expected under iOS 6.

The web page is loaded in viewWillAppear:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://somewhere.com/app-homepage/index.html";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView loadRequest:requestObj];

    [self.scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointZero];

}
```

The scroll view is dynamically resized in webViewDidFinishLoad:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;

    CGRect frame = webView.frame;

    frame.size.height = 1;

    webView.frame = frame;

    CGSize fittingSize = [webView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];

    frame.size = fittingSize;

    self.webViewHeightConstraint.constant = frame.size.height;

    self.featuredCelebritiesButtonTopVerticalSpaceConstraint.constant = frame.size.height + 8;

    CGSize svContentSize = self.scrollView.contentSize;

    svContentSize.height = frame.size.height + 65;

    self.scrollView.contentSize = svContentSize;

    webView.frame = frame;

    [self.activity stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: disable the AutoLayout and it will start working!

Comment: I really don't think AutoLayout is the issue. When I was originally writing the code, it was a problem, but after adding code to reset the 2 AutoLayout constraints in webViewDidFinishLoading that solved any AutoLayout-related issues when I first created the home screen. Your suggestion seems to be all too common with iOS 7 issues and I honestly don't believe it's really the solution. There has to be an underlying difference in the life cycle between iOS 6 & 7 to be causing an issue like this. I'd rather find out a real solution as opposed to a hacky one.

Comment: i had the same issue and i wasn't able to find the solution of why ScrollView stops scrolling in iOS 7. Finally i had to disable the AutoLayout in my project and it solved the issue. Let me know if you find the solution for it

Comment: Personally, I suspect a bug in iOS 7. There does seem to be a lot of AutoLayout issues associated UIScrollView. At any rate for the time being, I modified my code where I'm popping the view controller to see if it's popping back to the home screen. If so, then I clear the navigation controller stack and force it to go to the home screen as if somebody had pressed the home icon in the toolbar. Very hacky, but I'd rather keep the benefits of AutoLayout, which works great for this screen except for the single use case that I'm having problems with. Thx for you suggestion though.